# Unexpected blue border while typing text react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

There is an unexpected blue border when I type text. Please check the image. I tried editing `control` styles by setting `border` zero or none and even removed `boxShadow`. But nothing works. Please check the image.

```
control: (provided) => ({ ...provided, boxShadow: 'none', border: 0, }),
```

[image]

Comment: Do you use any UI framework that styles the inputs?

Comment: No, I don't. Even all other inputs working fine (without any border/outline to the typing test).

Answer (score 9):

I found the issue. I was using one tailwind plugin `tailwindcss-forms`. It overrides the default behavior of some inputs. So there are 2 solutions to this.

1. Remove plugin from **tailwind.congif.js** file. Bascially remove this line `require('@tailwindcss/forms')`.
2. If you want to keep this plugin. Add this into your parent css file. e.g. **index.css**. `input[type='text']:focus { box-shadow: none; }`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specifically modify **react-select** input style while keep using the tailwindcss-forms, you can use [classNamePrefix](https://react-select.com/styles#using-classnames) props.

```
<Select
    classNamePrefix="select2-selection"
    ...
/>
```

Then in your **index.css** file, add this:

```
.select2-selection__input:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

This will change the input style specific for **react-select** component.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the blue box around the input while typing use this in Select tag:

```
styles={{
          input: (base) => ({
                    ...base,
                    "input:focus": {
                         boxShadow: "none",
                         },
                  })
       }}
```

This will remove the separate focus for input inside the react select field.

Comment: Hey Thanks! Worked Great!