# How do I remove the blue border of input component in react-select component?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, jsx, tailwind-css, react-select

As I click on component to type, the blue box appear in component as shown in image below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zkPc.png)

Below is the code I am using:

```
<div class="hidden xl:flex flex-col w-3/6">
      <div class="p-8 dark:bg-gray-700 bg-gray-50 rounded-xl">
        <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-5">Job Filters</h2>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <span className="font-semibold mb-2">Location</span>
          <Select
            options={[{ value: "ABC", label: "ABC" }]}
            style={selectStyle.style}
            theme={selectStyle.theme}
          ></Select>
 //Rest of the components
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Custom Style for component:

```
const selectStyle = {
    style: {
      control: (base) => ({
        ...base,
        padding: "0.13rem",
        borderRadius: "5px",
      }),
    },
    theme: (theme) => ({
      ...theme,
      colors: {
        ...theme.colors,
        primary: "#FB8122",
        primary25: "#FC984A",
        primary75: "#FEDCC2",
        primary50: "#FDC69A",
      },
    }),
  };
```

I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in Advance.

I tried to refer documentation [doc](https://react-select.com/components) but not getting any clue.

Comment: totally remove or just change color?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/52614304/125981

Comment: OR maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/69307885/125981 - so you can see why more clarity will help here as this seems more like your image linked to (perhaps put it IN the question instead of a link) or this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71990662/125981

Comment: Thanks.. stackoverflow.com/q/69307885/125981 This works for me.